# Difficulty starting ruby on rails server with sql2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to this so please be lenient if I am not asking in a good way.
I have seen some similar questions such as: [Can't start rails server mysql2 gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487703/cant-start-rails-server-mysql2-gem)
however I have not been able to solve this problem through their answers.

I am trying to start a ruby on rails server, I have installed MySQL, ruby, rails, and the gems successfully. I have also installed the sql2 gem successfully. I have created a project and changed to its directory. When I type:

**rails server**

to create a server, I get the following message in the terminal:

**C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in 'require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.2/mysql2 (LoadError)**

followed by a lot more text but I believe this line is the root of the problem.

This is what is in the mysql2.rb file:

`RUBY_VERSION =~ /(\d+.\d+)/
require "mysql2/#{$1}/mysql2"`

In the error it says it cannot load **mysql2/2.2/mysql2**,
when I navigate to the mysql2 folder, there is only a 2.0 and a 2.1 folder, no 2.2 folder. Is this the problem? If so do you know how I fix it?

Comment: Just mention the version that's there in your path , like gem "mysql2" , ~2.1

Comment: should it be mentioned in the system or user variable path?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by mention the version in the path

Comment: This is my current user variable path: C:\Ruby22-x64\bin

Answer (score 0):

Change `require "mysql2/#{$1}/mysql2"` to `require "mysql2/2.1/mysql2"` in your `mysql2.rb` file, I think the issue is that it's looking for the version that doesn't exist, give that a try and get back to us if it doesn't work.

Regards,
Grant

Comment: Ok so I did what you said there and I get the following message: **C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in 'require':126: The specified module could not be found.** - **C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/2.1/mysql2.so (LoadError)**