# Error "...cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.0/mysql2 (LoadError)". On Windows XP with Ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mysql2, ruby-2.0

The command `rails server` throws this error.

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `require': cannot load
 such file -- mysql2/2.0/mysql2 (LoadError)
```

I use **Ruby 2.0.0** from [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/) on Windows XP box.

I figured out what is the problem but I don't know how to solve it. The problem is that there is no any `2.0/` directory in the `mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32` gem. This is the gem that `rails` installs as its dependency from **Gemfile**:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
     ... many gems here
     mysql2 (0.3.11-x86-mingw32)
     ... many gems here
DEPENDENCIES
  ...
  mysql2
  ...
```

This is what is in that `mysql2.rb` file:

```
# C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32\lib\mysql2\mysql2.rb

RUBY_VERSION =~ /(\d+.\d+)/
require "mysql2/#{$1}/mysql2"  # <<-- this is that #2 line that throws an error
```

It is obvious that it takes the current Ruby version number and uses it as the path segment to reach some `mysql2` file. In fact it is `mysql2.so` file. As I use **Ruby 2.0.0** the path segment is `2.0`:

```
mysql2/2.0/mysql2
```

Ok, now lets see how that directory of `mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32` gem looks like:

```
dir: C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32\lib\mysql2\
```

[image]

No any `2.0/` directory.

I know the issue about **libmysql.dll**. I have it in my `C:\Ruby200\bin`. It doesn't help.

I read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5368767/1114926 from the creator of RubyInstaller. I tried but it didn't help. It works for `Ruby 1.9.3` because there is `1.9/` directory. But it doesn't work for `Ruby 2.0.0`.

How to solve it?

---

**UPD 1:**

Thank you for your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15613521/1114926). I've tried. Unfortunately I have `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.` error:

```
C:\>gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:431:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (Runtim
eError)
You have to install development tools first.
... other code follows here...
```

It says:

> You have to install development tools first.

But I have full DevKit installed, RubyInstaller installs it. Can't understand what else does it need.

I've already posted an issue to `mysql2` GitHub page https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/364. No answers yet.

Answer (score 13):

Had the absolutely same issue on Windows 7 x64 with Ruby 2.0.0 and DevKit 4.7.

The following steps helped me.

1. > gem uninstall mysql2
2. Download last MySQL connector from http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip
3. Extract it to **C:\connector-6.0.2**
4. > gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\connector-6.0.2\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\connector-6.0.2\include" --with-mysql-dir="C:\connector-6.0.2"'

Or even shorter:

> gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-dir="C:\connector-6.0.2"

Comment: Yeah, that worked! But first - you need to use **cmd.exe**, not powershell! Second - sometimes you have to force gem version in your **Gemfile** to, e.g. 0.3.13, because bundler is installing 0.2.6-mingw compiled version...

Comment: Use following if above is not working:- 
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\connector-6.0.2\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\connector-6.0.2\include"

Comment: @RohitPorwal yours worked for me, but you're missing the final ' in the command, i.e, should be: gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\connector-6.0.2\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\connector-6.0.2\include"'

Answer (score 5):

uninstall `mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32`, gems compiled before `Ruby200` won't work. You have to compile it yourself. 
If you run `gem uninstall mysql2` and there is a non compiled version listed then just uninstall `mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32` - the compiled version else...

Installation
`gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby`. that would work.

Follow this guide on installing devkit http://rubyonwindowsguides.github.com/book/ch02-04.html.

Then try again.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the same behavior when I try to install Redmine on windows XP

- when I try to do the "rake generate_secret_token", I got "cannot load
  such file -- mysql2/2.0/mysql2 (LoadError)"
- and when I try to re build mysql2 using --platform=ruby, I got the
  same message as you green.

for the moment, I am stucked there ... but if anybody has anything to allow me to move forward, it will be very welcome.
I will keep informed as well

antoine

Answer (score 2):

I almost done the same what @odiszapc described. Uninstall old gem, download mysql-connector-c-noinstall, unzip, but finally I used this command to build native gem:

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-dir=/c/connector-6.0.2
```

(If you use git-bash then you can use unix style directory syntax.)

Comment: Please note, if you run bundle install or bundle update, than mingw version of mysql2 gem will be installed again. You have to 'gem uninstall' it always...

Comment: I had to do gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-dir=/c/connector-6.0.2 --with-mysql-dir=/c/connector-6.0.2 ... because compilation failed and I noticed there are references to ${mysql-dir}/include.

Answer (score 2):

Copy paste from that link: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/359. It worked for me.

---

If after installing the gem, you get an error:

> "The specified module could not be found.
>   C:/Devel/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so"

That can be fixed by copying `libmysql.dll` to Ruby's bin folder.