# Load Error - Using MySQL with Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, cygwin, sqlite3-ruby

I have been trying to use SQL with Ruby on Rails for quite sometime now and cannot seem to make it work.

I've pretty much given up on SQLite, so my focus is now on MySQL. I have fully installed the program and it works on its own. However I cannot get it to work with Ruby on Rails.

Below is the message I get when I start a new project and choose MySQL as the database.

```
    C:\rails_projects>rails new first2_app -d mysql
      create
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/images/rails.png
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
      create  app/models/.gitkeep
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  doc
      create  doc/README_FOR_APP
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
      create  log
      create  log/.gitkeep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  script
      create  script/rails
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
      create  test/functional
      create  test/functional/.gitkeep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.gitkeep
      create  test/unit
      create  test/unit/.gitkeep
      create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.0.4)
Using i18n (0.6.1)
Installing multi_json (1.7.3)
Using activesupport (3.2.13)
Using builder (3.0.4)
Using activemodel (3.2.13)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.4)
Using rack (1.4.5)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using hike (1.2.2)
Installing tilt (1.4.1)
Using sprockets (2.2.2)
Using actionpack (3.2.13)
Using mime-types (1.23)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.12)
Installing mail (2.5.4)
Using actionmailer (3.2.13)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
Using activerecord (3.2.13)
Using activeresource (3.2.13)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
Using execjs (1.4.0)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
Installing json (1.8.0)
Using rdoc (3.12.2)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using railties (3.2.13)
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Using jquery-rails (2.2.1)
Installing mysql2 (0.3.11)
Using rails (3.2.13)
Installing sass (3.2.9)
Using sass-rails (3.2.6)
Installing uglifier (2.1.0)
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Post-install message from mysql2:

================================================================================
======================

  You've installed the binary version of mysql2.
  It was built using MySQL Connector/C version 6.0.2.
  It's recommended to use the exact same version to avoid potential issues.

  At the time of building this gem, the necessary DLL files where available
  in the following download:

  http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0
.2-win32.zip/from/pick

  And put lib\libmysql.dll file in your Ruby bin directory, for example C:\Ruby\
bin

================================================================================
======================
```

However, when I proceed to run rails server, I get the following error:

```
C:\rails_projects\first2_app>rails server
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:
in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.0/mysql2 (LoadError)           

    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:
in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:9:
in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:9:
in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:
in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:
in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:
in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:
in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:
in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:
in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:
in `require'
        from C:/rails_projects/first2_app/config/application.rb:7:
in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:
in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:
in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:
in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:
in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I have tried almost everything I have come across in related StackExchange questions/answers including RubyVersionManager, DevKit, moving various .dll and .a files to C/Ruby/Bin etc etc but without much luck.

Any advice would be much appreciated! I really want to start programming with Ruby on Rails and hate that I am stuck at the door....

Cheers =D

**UPDATE 1: (Attempt at Linux Environment)**

Hello, the consensus seems to attempt running in Linux.

So I followed this guy's instructions on using Cygwin > http://youtu.be/hwo3Eda_ev0

And all is going well so far =)

Comment: I don't know a lot about Ruby on Rails on Windows, but have you tried the post-installed message of the gem mysql2? Anyway, if you are a beginner with RoR, I recommend you to try with Linux, it's really easier and you will have less headaches in the future :).

Comment: totally agree with @Pigueiras, should not use Rails on Windows. I'm a windows user myself but develop rails in Mac at work and in VM at home

Comment: At this point willing to try anything. I will post back on progress with using Linux

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

To download the zip in http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip/from/pick and copy the libmysql.dll file from there to your ruby directory (C:/Ruby200/bin). Then the access to MySQL from the Rails application should work.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604058/error-cannot-load-such-file-mysql2-2-0-mysql2-loaderror-on-windows-xp

Comment: Hi Victor, I did that with no success. I also tried all the suggestions people gave in the link you shared "line by line" and still no success =(