# Cannot Connect to MySQL Database in Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails and I'm going through a tutorial on Lynda.com, Rails 4 Essentials. I'm on a Windows 7 x64 machine and I'm trying to connect the MySQL database to the Rails app. I've successfully created the database and created a new user.

I had issues running the mysql2 gem and I could only get version 0.3.11 to work (it's on version 0.3.16 as of this post). I copied the libmysql.dll from the C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector.C 6.1\lib to my C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.0.0\bin directory as the instructions stated.

Everything seems to be ok at this point.

I configured my database.yml file to match my database credentials (I had to create this from scratch, nothing was generated when I ran mysql2).

```html
#config\database.yml
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: simple_cms_development
  username: craig
  password: password
  host: 127.0.0.1
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: simple_cms_test
  username: craig
  password: password
  host: 127.0.0.1
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: simple_cms_production
  username: craig
  password: password
  host: 127.0.0.1
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I got to try to connect my database with MySQL using:

```html
rake db:schema:dump
```

and I get this crap:

```html
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.0/mysql2
```

I see a directory called mysql2/1.9 and there is a file called mysql.so in there but there is no 2.0.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The joys of developing on a windows machine :)

I suggest you check this question - it looks like the same problem.

[Error "...cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.0/mysql2 (LoadError)". On Windows XP with Ruby 2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604058/error-cannot-load-such-file-mysql2-2-0-mysql2-loaderror-on-windows-xp)

Comment: I should have mentioned I went through that thread with not luck. Still trying...

Comment: ok, next guess, it's a path problem.  Can you (from your rails directory) type `mysql2/2.0/mysql2` and get anything?  Try to find that mysql2 file.  Sorry I'm not much help, I switched to Mac and haven't had to go through this grief.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get passed this issue by starting fresh. I followed these set of videos to set up Ruby, MySQL, and Rails on my Windows 7 x64 machine.

http://youtu.be/C5S7vjN6GLc

Worked like a gem, I'm rockin' and rollin' now.