# Ruby on Rails - cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.2/mysql2 (LoadError)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, heroku

I was using SQLite for my Rails project but when I heard that Heroku doesn't support SQLite, I switched to MYSQL.

After switching my database, I started my rails server "rails s" but it gives me the following error:

```
    C:\Sites\simple_cms>rails server
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `require'
: cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.2/mysql2 (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2
:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `r
equire'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<
top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `requ
ire'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `bloc
k (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each
'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `bloc
k in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each
'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `requ
ire'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks
.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks
.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks
.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks
.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks
.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top
 (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

This is my gemfile:

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
```

I searched thoroughly, found some answers but it didn't work.

I pasted my `libmysql.dll` file from `Program Files/MySQL Server 5.6` to `Ruby/bin` but still no luck. I performed the following commands:

```
gem uninstall mysql2

gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby
```

I followed this tutorial and still got the same error: [Error "...cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.0/mysql2 (LoadError)". On Windows XP with Ruby 2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604058/error-cannot-load-such-file-mysql2-2-0-mysql2-loaderror-on-windows-xp)

I will highly appreciate it if someone will help me out, so that I can deploy it to Heroku.

Thanks.

Comment: Got same error - will report back if fix.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the `mysql2` gem is not installing with its native dependencies. In previous versions of Ruby, this would have triggered the [`unable to build native gem extension`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/error-installing-mysql2-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension) error:

[image]

Something has changed in `Ruby 2.2` so that you *can* install the gem without it building the native extension. This does not mean the problem is resolved however - and so you have to ensure you install the gem with the appropriate dependencies.

[Tutorial](https://medium.com/@frontlineutils/installing-the-mysql2-rubyonrails-gem-on-windows-7-8-a028f44d87f3):

1. [Download C-Connector from MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) (note your version of Ruby -- if you're using 64 bit, download the 64 bit version)
2. Unzip / Install the MYSQL C-Connector folder onto your HDD (don't have any spaces in the path)
3. Run the following command: `gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:/your-mysql-connector-path"'`
4. This *should* install the gem with the files it needs
5. Then you can copy `libmysql.dll` from `C:/your-mysql-connector-path` -> c:/your-ruby-install/bin`

The difference between this install and the previous one will be that this *should* mention that the native gem extensions are being installed (`This could take a while`), which suggests that Ruby is looking at the library.

This time, if it installs correctly, it should work for you.

--

If you're still seeing an error, you'll have to uninstall any existing versions of the `mysql2` gem on your system:

[image: How to install mysql2.]

If you're getting an error, you just need to type `gem uninstall mysql2`, select `all` and then repeat the steps above.

Comment: Giving this method a go but it throws back:
invalid option: --with-mysql-dir=C:

Comment: You just have to encapsulate the path in quotations, as per my answre

Comment: I get 'invalid option' regardless of quotes. The answer in general also does not change it at all.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I also have the invalid option error. Screen shot: http://postimg.org/image/vb1rsm713/ Thanks!

Comment: Solved the problem the command should be: gem install mysql2 -- -with-mysql-dir="C:/your-mysql-connector-path"

Comment: UPDATE: Following the rest of these steps did not solve the original issue :(

Comment: I know what the issue is - amended my documentation

Answer (score 3):

In step 3 above I had to use an extra pair of '-' and no quotes around the path.

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=C:\mysql-connector-dir
```

I'm using Win 7

Answer (score 2):

I just got them same problem after updating from Ruby 2.1.5 to 2.2.1. The problem seems to be the `mysql2` gem that's used by Rails as a binding to `libmysql`. Apparently it does not support the Ruby 2.2 branch but only 2.0 and 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem so I switched to using RubyInstaller. I no longer have the problem.