# rails error cannot load such file --nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So if I type pretty much anything, I'm getting this error and I'm not finding a solution.

Discovered it while trying to install foundation, but I'm sure it was a problem before. This is a brand new (attempted) install of ruby on rails.

This error comes up if I try to rake, generate controllers, or anything else. Please help.

```
C:\Sites\Project>rails g
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `require': cannot load such file -- nok
ogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `rescue in <top (required)
>'
   ...etc
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [RubyInstaller 2.2.1 and Rails - Rake cannot load Nokogiri](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985328/rubyinstaller-2-2-1-and-rails-rake-cannot-load-nokogiri)

Answer (score 4):

You need to install nokogiri, try to install nokogiri with the command:

`sudo gem install nokogiri`

Some gems in order to work properly needs the nokogiri gem, so you need to have it installed, in the nokogiri website there is a very well documented tutorial on installation for multiple OS [installing nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html).

If you're running Yosemite on a Mac you may need to run this:

`gem update --system`

As the installation guide shows as well, that's an issue with some new Yosemite installations.

When you install it successfully on your machine, you can continue to work as normal, *generate controllers, run rake, start the server, bundle install, etc*.

If the installation with sudo didn't work, neither a bundle install, then read the note below and try again to sudo/bundle.

> Note: in order to install nokogiri you need to have installed the
>   Command Line Tools as well, if you're working on OSX.

So try running:

`xcode-select --install`

In your Terminal.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using MacOS with M1 chip and encounter this problem. I'm running termianl without Rosetta 2 and using ARM version homebrew. It seems that nokogiri dependency is still x86 version when running on ARM chip, so after installing error occurs. I solve this problem with following steps:
First, Install nokogiri specifying use-system-libraries. This will install correct version for ARM processer, according to [Installing Nokogiri - Installing Using Standard System Libraries - Nokogiri](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#installing-using-standard-system-libraries).

```
brew install libxml2 libxslt
gem install nokogiri --platform=ruby -- --use-system-libraries
```

Second, run following command to uninstall nokogiri, and gem will ask that you have two versions of nokogiri and which you want to uninstall. Choose the x86_64 version and uninstall it(for me, I uninstalled nokogiri-1.13.6-x86_64-darwin).

```
sudo gem uninstall nokogiri
```

That's all, problem solved.

Comment: This solved it for me! With Nokogiri 1.14.2

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problems on my Mac OS. And assuming you have the libxml2 installed with homebrew, for me was necessary to do these steps:

```
$ brew list libxml2
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.7/bin/xml2-config
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.7/bin/xmlcatalog
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.7/bin/xmllint
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.7/include/libxml2/ (47 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.7/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.7/lib/cmake/libxml2/libxml2-config.cmake
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.7/lib/pkgconfig/libxml-2.0.pc
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.7/lib/python2.7/ (4 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.7/lib/ (3 other files)
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.7/share/aclocal/libxml.m4
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.7/share/doc/ (153 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.7/share/gtk-doc/ (55 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.7/share/man/ (4 files)
$  sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/* .
$ irb             
>> require 'nokogiri'
=> true
```

If you don't have libxml2 installed:

```
brew install libxml2
```

Answer (score 0):

**In my case I fixed my issue by updating ruby to 3.0.2 with rvm.**

Started with ruby 2.6.3 from MacOS

```
which ruby
ruby -v
```

Install ruby 3.0.2

```
rvm install ruby-3.0.2
```

Check to make sure `ruby` command is updated

```
ruby -v
which ruby
// should be version 3.0.2 in the /Users/yourprofilename/.rvm/ruby-3.0.2/bin/ruby
// instead of the original /usr/local/bin
```

Install the packages that you originally tried to use - in my case:

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
bundle exec middleman server // This is for running my slatedocs project
```

Old question but I hope this helps someone if they encounter a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to run Rails server, it kept failing by saying the following error.

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)

The following steps helped me to solve the issue.

Run `gem uninstall nokogiri`

Add `gem "nokogiri", ">= 1.6.7.rc"` to your Gemfile

Run `bundle install`

Run `bundle update nokogiri` if bundle has locked Nokogiri at some version.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33410164/5210943

Answer (score -1):

Please try in console:
`gem install nokogiri`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I disagree. I believe this answers it very directly.

Comment: This step is mentioned on nokogiri's website https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html:
```brew install libxml2 libxslt && gem install nokogiri --platform=ruby -- --use-system-libraries``` but the same issue! :-(