# Installed RailsFTW and I can't even make a new project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I was having this difficulty

[In Windows, rails s gives 3 different errors, I fix one and get a bunch more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448157/rails-s-gives-3-different-errors-i-fix-one-and-get-a-bunch-more)

So then I found this project RailsFTW  I don't know if that's a good thing or a bad thing but i'm guessing it's a bad thing.

After installing that, now I can't even create a project

```
C:\rubyblah>ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]

C:\rubyblah>rails -v
Rails 4.2.1

C:\rubyblah>where rails
C:\RailsFTW421215\bin\rails
C:\RailsFTW421215\bin\rails.bat
C:\Ruby22-x64\bin\rails
C:\Ruby22-x64\bin\rails.bat

C:\rubyblah>rails -v
Rails 4.2.1

C:\rubyblah>rails new sdfa
      create
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/mailers/.keep
      create  app/models/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/secrets.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.2
Installing minitest 5.6.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.1
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile 0.6.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.6
Installing loofah 2.0.2
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
Using actionview 4.2.1
Installing rack 1.6.1
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.1
Installing globalid 0.3.5
Using activejob 4.2.1
Installing mime-types 2.6.1
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.2.1
Using activemodel 4.2.1
Using arel 6.0.0
Using activerecord 4.2.1
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using bundler 1.9.1
Using columnize 0.9.0

LoadError: cannot load such file -- devkit.rb
An error occurred while installing byebug (5.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '5.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.

C:\rubyblah>
```

So I looked up about that error with devkit.rb

I tried

```
C:\dkt>ruby dk.rb init
[INFO] found RubyInstaller v2.1.5 at C:/RailsFTW421215
[INFO] found RubyInstaller v2.2.2 at C:/Ruby22-x64

Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated
'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all
of the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.

C:\dkt>ruby dk.rb install
[INFO] Installing 'C:/RailsFTW421215/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/defaults/operat
ing_system.rb'
[INFO] Installing 'C:/RailsFTW421215/lib/ruby/site_ruby/devkit.rb'
[INFO] Skipping existing gem override for 'C:/Ruby22-x64'
[WARN] Skipping existing DevKit helper library for 'C:/Ruby22-x64'

C:\dkt>
```

and now it's even worse

C:\rubyblah>rails new efsre

now even worse

```
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/RailsFTW421215/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
generating generator-i386-mingw32.def
compiling generator.c
In file included from c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:109:14: error: size of array 'ruby_ch
eck_sizeof_voidp' is negative
In file included from c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_obj_wb_unprotect':
c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1234:9: warning: cast to pointer from
 integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1235:6: warning: cast to pointer from
 integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1238:2: warning: cast to pointer from
 integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_obj_written':
c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1253:9: warning: cast to pointer from
 integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_num2char_inline':
c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1324:35: warning: cast to pointer fro
m integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1324:35: warning: cast to pointer fro
m integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1324:35: warning: cast to pointer fro
m integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1325:9: warning: cast to pointer from
 integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1325:9: warning: cast to pointer from
 integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1325:9: warning: cast to pointer from
 integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_class_of':
c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1642:12: warning: cast to pointer fro
m integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_type':
c:/RailsFTW421215/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1659:12: warning: cast to pointer fro
m integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
In file included from generator.c:1:0:
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h: In function 'fbuffer_append_str':
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:127:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [
-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:127:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [
-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:127:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [
-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'convert_UTF8_to_JSON_ASCII':
generator.c:129:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:129:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:129:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:130:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:130:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:130:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'convert_UTF8_to_JSON':
generator.c:227:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:227:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:227:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:228:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:228:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:228:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_configure':
generator.c:559:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:559:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:559:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:560:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:560:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:560:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:567:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:567:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:567:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:568:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:568:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:568:33: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:575:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:575:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:575:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:576:40: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:576:40: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:576:40: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:583:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:583:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:583:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:584:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:584:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:584:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:591:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:591:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:591:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:592:37: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:592:37: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:592:37: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'set_state_ivars':
generator.c:640:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:640:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:640:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:642:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:642:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:642:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'generate_json_object':
generator.c:727:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:727:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:727:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'generate_json_array':
generator.c:773:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:773:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:773:20: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'isArrayOrObject':
generator.c:930:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:930:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:930:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:931:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:931:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c:931:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-
pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_indent_set':
generator.c:1055:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1055:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1055:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1064:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1064:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1064:32: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_space_set':
generator.c:1093:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1093:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1093:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1102:31: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1102:31: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1102:31: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_space_before_set':
generator.c:1129:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1129:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1129:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1138:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1138:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1138:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_object_nl_set':
generator.c:1167:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1167:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1167:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1175:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1175:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1175:35: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c: In function 'cState_array_nl_set':
generator.c:1202:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1202:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1202:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1210:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1210:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
generator.c:1210:34: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to
-pointer-cast]
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsFTW421215/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8
.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsFTW421215/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/j
son-1.8.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Would I be closer to solving this if I got rid of RailsFTW? I thought it might have a community of windows users that happily have it working smoothly in windows, but I see no RailsFTW forum of any kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget RubyFTW

The accepted answer for this one applies

[In Windows, rails s gives 3 different errors, I fix one and get a bunch more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448157/in-windows-rails-s-gives-3-different-errors-i-fix-one-and-get-a-bunch-more)

You make sure to install ruby for windows with a version of ruby that is recommended for windows.. so at the time of writing - not the latest version, and not 64 bit.  Ruby 2.1.6 32bit.  That is the latest Ruby that is stable / works for Windows.