# fails to start Webrick server uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveM odelHelper (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm going through Lynda tutorials and i'm trying to start a server , but i get an error saying

> C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers.
>   rb:40:in `': uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveM
>   odelHelper (NameError) .

I did run bundle install  before that . I copied here gem file as well

```
C:\Users\berutiel\Documents\sites\tut>bundle install
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.7.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.3
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile 0.6.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.0.2
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
Using actionview 4.2.3
Using rack 1.6.4
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.3
Using globalid 0.3.5
Using activejob 4.2.3
Using mime-types 2.6.1
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.2.3
Using activemodel 4.2.3
Using arel 6.0.2
Using activerecord 4.2.3
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using bundler 1.10.6
Using columnize 0.9.0
Using byebug 5.0.0
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using jbuilder 2.3.1  
Using mysql2 0.3.19
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.2.3
Using sprockets 3.2.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.3.2
Using rails 4.2.3
Using rdoc 4.2.0
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using tzinfo-data 1.2015.5
Using web-console 2.2.1
Bundle complete! 8 Gemfile dependencies, 44 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

> C:\Users\berutiel\Documents\sites\tut>rails server

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview- 4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers.
rb:40:in <module:Helpers>': uninitialized constant    ActionView::Helpers::ActiveM
odelHelper (NameError)
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-    4.2.3/lib/action_
view/helpers.rb:4:in <module:ActionView>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview- 4.2.3/lib/action_
view/helpers.rb:3:in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-  4.2.3/lib/action_
view/base.rb:5:in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_
view/base.rb:5:in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_co
nsole/template.rb:7:in <class:Template>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_co
nsole/template.rb:6:in <module:WebConsole>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-  2.2.1/lib/web_co
nsole/template.rb:1:in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_co
nsole.rb:12:in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_co
nsole.rb:12:in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web-co
nsole.rb:1:in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web-co
nsole.rb:1:in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:76:in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:76:in block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:72:in each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:72:in block in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:61:in each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:61:in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.r
b:134:in require'
    from   C:/Users/berutiel/Documents/sites/tut/config/application.rb:7:in <
top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in block in server'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in tap'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in server'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in run_command!'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/com
mands.rb:17:in <top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in require'
    from bin/rails:4:in <main>'
ource 'https://rubygems.org'
```

Gemfile

```
    # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
    gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
    # Use mysql as the database for Active Record
    gem 'mysql2'
    # Use SCSS for stylesheets
    #gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
    # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
    #gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
    #gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
    # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
    # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

    # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
    #gem 'jquery-rails'
    # Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read    more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
    #gem 'turbolinks'
    # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
    # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
    gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
    gem 'rack', '~> 1.6.4'
    # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
    # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

    # Use Unicorn as the app server
    # gem 'unicorn'

    # Use Capistrano for deployment
    # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

    group :development, :test do
    # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a      debugger console
    gem 'byebug'

    # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
    gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  end

  # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
  gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's weird. The error message you pasted appears to have a typo in it; can you confirm that there's really a space between the M and O of "Model" in this error message?

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveM odelHelper (NameError) .
```

Anyway I'd try troubleshooting this in a couple ways:

1. Can you verify that the Rails gem is installed, and is in the right place? In the app directory, run `bundle show nokogiri` to find out where the gem `nokogiri` is installed (or pick any other gem that doesn't appear to be giving errors), then run `bundle show rails` to verify that Rails is installed inside the same path.
2. Does `actionview` show up inside your `Gemfile.lock`? This file is the "compiled" version of your Gemfile and lists the exact version of every gem dependency your app has. Everything listed here should be installed, so open that and verify that ActionView is in the list. It definitely should be since the `rails` gem includes / depends on it.
3. Can you reproduce the problem with a brand new app? Start a fresh app by going out of your app directory, tying `rails new test_app`, then `cd` in and run `bundle install` to install the default gems for this app, then run `rails server` to see if the error shows up as before. If it DOES reproduce with a fresh app, then you have much more concrete steps for the problem that you can post in the question here to make it easier for us to troubleshoot.

Good luck! Initial setup with the Rails environment can be intensely frustrating, but It Gets Better.

Answer (score 0):

I went through this solution ,[RubyInstaller 2.2.1 and Rails - Rake cannot load Nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985328/rubyinstaller-2-2-1-and-rails-rake-cannot-load-nokogiri/29196632#29196632)

The problem is resolved 
Thanks to everyone