# require nokogiri issue with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, git

I've installed nokogiri using the "gem install nokogiri" command in git bash and shows me the gem has installed successfully. But when I try to run `rails s` it gives me the require error for `nokogiri`. I am not sure what's the reason and how to solve it.

I am using `windows 10`

I am using `Ruby 2.2.3`

**Installing nokogiri**

[image]

**Error that I get**

[image]

Comment: Did you try to force nokogiri to install using system libs?  e.g. `gem install nokogiri --use-system-libraries`

Comment: it's giving `invalid option --use-system-libraries`. I am using windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid nokogiri won't work for the combination of Ruby 2.2 and mingw. According to https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1256, it is currently only supported for Ruby 1.9, 2.0 and 2.1.

There is a workaround with manual install of libraries, as described in [RubyInstaller 2.2.1 and Rails - Rake cannot load Nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985328/rubyinstaller-2-2-1-and-rails-rake-cannot-load-nokogiri), but it seems to be a bit tricky. So if Ruby 2.2 is not that critical for you, you may want to downgrade to Ruby 2.1.

And as a general recommendation -- development on Ruby/Rails using Windows it not really optimal, consider switching to Linux

Comment: The first part answer is technically correct, albeit the last part doesn't make it seem like a very welcoming community, when `Nokogiri 1.6.7` is released, which should be pretty soon, it will be fixed so that you don't you can compile nokogiri on Windows. Which will fix problems like these where the binary isn't included and the gem won't compile natively on Windows.

Comment: Fair enough. Still, if you are talking about development on Windows, I'm just sharing my own experience. It tried developing on Windows, but two years ago switched to Linux as a development platform and, I must admit, it makes many things much simpler. Starting from the fact that I do not rely on RubyInstaller anymore (which has a significant delay in version adoption), down to significant simplification of workflows, concerning native gems, which are much more straightforward in Linux. What you wrote, @Azolo, is definitely correct wrt Nokogiri, but there are many others around...

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue with nokogiri.
This fixed nokogiri issue for me on ruby 2.2:

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
```

and then

```
sudo gem install nokogiri
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey, I am using windows 10.