# Is Nokogiri necessary for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I updated my Ruby from 1.9 to 2.2 and I found that the Nokogiri gem doesn't support Ruby 2.2 on Windows. Nokogiri was not in my Gemfile, but when I run `bundle install` it is automatically added. Maybe there are some dependency for it?

This is a very small project and I don't understand its necessity for the project.

Is it possible to use Ruby 2.2 without Nokogiri? Or should I downgrade to 1.9 again?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985328/rubyinstaller-2-2-1-and-rails-rake-cannot-load-nokogiri

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is a dependency of some gem, which is included in your Gemfile.

You can search for `nokogiri` in your Gemfile.lock to find a gem which is requiring it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Nokogiri is required by `rails-dom-testing` which is required by Action Pack and Action View in Rails 4.2.3, so it seems difficult to bypass it.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1256

tl;dr, in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'nokogiri', '>= 1.6.7.rc3'
```

for Windows.