# MySQL error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Install ruby and ruby on rails on my windows 8.1

I have a problem when launching the server

```
C:\Sites\testing>rails s
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.2/mysql2 (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from C:/Sites/testing/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

C:\Sites\testing>

Help me please. 
Thank.

Comment: Have you installed the mysql2 gem and run `bundle install`?

Comment: This guy's on windows, that other question wasn't **and** none of the answers were accepted or even upvoted much.

Comment: Felipe, Windows is a huge pain to develop Rails apps on. There are like 1000 steps to getting an app written, and you're on step 5 and facing your first big annoying problem, and between here and 1000 there are another 300 other issues entirely related to running on Windows. Do yourself a favor and use Vagrant or Docker or something and run a Linux virtual machine to develop your Rails app in.

Comment: Thank for your help, I will take your advice. :D

Answer (score 0):

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925628/ruby-on-rails-cannot-load-such-file-mysql2-2-2-mysql2-loaderror) where it seems that someone is having a similar issues to yours. Looks like some have suggested trying RubyInstaller.

Comment: I do the same on the tutorial and the error persists. thank for your help