# cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.4/mysql2 - Ruby 2.4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have Ruby 2.4 and trying to install `mysql2` . I follow the instructions from internet:

1. `gem uninstall mysql2` - if needed;
2. download mysql connector;
3. `gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\conn\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\conn\include"'` and see message - `1 gem is installed`;
4. copy file `libmysql.lib` to `rubyFolder/bin`

If run `rails s` I see this message:

> Could not find mysql2-0.4.8-x64-mingw32 in any of the sources Run bundle install to install missing gems.

and I do it - `bundle`, but after that, if I run again `rails s` I see same error:

> C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.4/mysql2 (LoadError)

I am using Windows.
One solution is to switch to Ruby 2.3, but is there way to use `mysql2` with Ruby 2.4 ?

Comment: Have you included `mysql2` **in the `Gemfile`**? You do not need to install the library locally via `gem install`; you need to install it as part of the project's dependencies - i.e. include it in the `Gemfile`, and then run `bundle install`.

Comment: Yes, it is in GemFile - `gem 'mysql2'` . This is ruby 2.4 with MySQL2, I follow steps from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925628/ruby-on-rails-cannot-load-such-file-mysql2-2-2-mysql2-loaderror and it is not working. Still same error.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Or you have downgraded the Ruby to 2.3 ?