# trying to run command rails server (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2

im trying to get started with rails. I have made a rails project and now im trying to start the server but get this.

```
C:\Users\Home\Documents\Sites\simple_cms>rails server
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.2/mysql2 (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Home/Documents/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

my gemfile has gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'

windows 7

ruby version 2.2.1

rails 4.2.1

mySql server version 5.6.24

Edit:
Couldn't find a solution that worked for me so i installed a different version of rails and it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed `mysql2` gem using `bundle install` and that `bundle install` has returned successful installation.

Comment: The gem is installed and bundle does say its using it already.

Answer (score 0):

@James, This issue has been already raised so follow these links and hope this may help you.

1) [Error "...cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.0/mysql2 (LoadError)". On Windows XP with Ruby 2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604058/error-cannot-load-such-file-mysql2-2-0-mysql2-loaderror-on-windows-xp)

2) [Ruby on Rails - cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.2/mysql2 (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925628/ruby-on-rails-cannot-load-such-file-mysql2-2-2-mysql2-loaderror)

3) https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3456

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
```

to

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.11'
```

I think that maximum compatible version with Windows is 0.3.11. Then run again `bundle install`