# Can't get WAMP MySQL to work with Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, wamp

I am trying to use my WAMP MySQL for a Ruby on Rails installation on my Windows 7 system.  I am getting errors (see below) when I try to start the rails WEBrick server.

I've installed the complete Ruby on Rails environment successfully, including the mysql2 gem.  When installing the mysql2 gem, I referenced the location of the lib and includes folders of the WAMP mysql and it successfully installed:

```
C:\wamp\www\simple_cms>gem install mysql2 --no-document -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\lib\" --with-mysql-include="C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\include\"

======================================================================================================

 \ You've installed the binary version of mysql2.
  It was built using MySQL Connector/C version 6.1.5.
  It's recommended to use the exact same version to avoid potential issues.

  At the time of building this gem, the necessary DLL files were retrieved from:
  http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-6.1.5-winx64.zip

 \ This gem *includes* vendor/libmysql.dll with redistribution notice in vendor/README.

======================================================================================================

Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32
1 gem installed
```

I copied the libmysql.dll from "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\lib\libmysql.dll" to "C:\Ruby22-x64\bin\libmysql.dll".

I get the following error when I try to start WEBrick

```
C:\wamp\www\simple_cms>rails server
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.2/mysql2 (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
        from C:/wamp/www/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I have also tried using the libmysql.dll included with the mysql2 gem located at "C:\Ruby22-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32\vendor\libmysql.dll" and copying that to "C:\Ruby22-x64\bin\libmysql.dll".  That also gave the above errors.

I can access mysql from the command line:

```
C:\wamp\www\simple_cms>mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.24, for Win64 (x86)
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have mysql path in the Environment variables of windows?

Comment: For the WAMP MySQL path?  Yes

Relevant Path is ...C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin;C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2...

Comment: Have you check this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604058/error-cannot-load-such-file-mysql2-2-0-mysql2-loaderror-on-windows-xp/15613521#15613521

Comment: I don't think that question is my problem.  My whole path exists.  "C:\Ruby22-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32\lib\mysql2\mysql2.rb"