# Rails Server not Working (LoadErrror mysql2) Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle, mysql2

I am trying to run rails server command but it showing mysql2 Load Error. I will place my Error log here
[image: Error Log]

I searched many places.
I tried to install from my bundle itself using "gem install mysql2 --ruby=platform" command using connector c "libmysql.dll" file pasted in ruby/bin but no use.

I actually have MySQL installed on my system long back when I was doing JDBC connections. Its SQL server version 5.0- Is that version causing this error? Or Do I need to uninstall the MySQL from my system and install Latest Version! 
And a doubt for me is how is this MySQL Server 5.0 connected to Rails as I no I have no idea about it, because while installation I used Connector C 6.1 for mysql2 installation from the Command Promt!

I tried [Ruby on Rails - cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.2/mysql2 (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925628/ruby-on-rails-cannot-load-such-file-mysql2-2-2-mysql2-loaderror)

I also tried [Error "...cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.0/mysql2 (LoadError)". On Windows XP with Ruby 2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604058/error-cannot-load-such-file-mysql2-2-0-mysql2-loaderror-on-windows-xp)
But I am getting the same error.

I think I have given all the details regarding versions and what I did!
I tried doing this like 50 times but no progress! I hope I will get my problem solved !Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following below instructions can help you.

```
gem uninstall mysql2
```

Download last MySQL connector from http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip

Extract it to `C:\connector-6.0.2`

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\connector-
6.0.2\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\connector-6.0.2\include" --with-mysql-
dir="C:\connector-6.0.2"'
```

Or even shorter:

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-dir="C:\connector-6.0.2"
```

Comment: Hai I did what you said. I downloaded rar file and extractd it to c:\connector-6.0.2
And I uninstalled mysql2 from cmd
First, I pasted libmysql.dll from the connector-6.0.2\lib to the rails\bin folder
Then I performed installation using the above command you gave.
It installed.
Now when I run the rails server command it shows some error 
uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper (Name Error)

Answer (score 0):

im not using windows. but seems to be duplicate with posts like this ([Error "...cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.0/mysql2 (LoadError)". On Windows XP with Ruby 2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604058/error-cannot-load-such-file-mysql2-2-0-mysql2-loaderror-on-windows-xp))