# Please install mysql2 adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, mysql2, dbmigrate

I'm new of rails, and i have this big problem. I'm running rails 3.2.9 and Ruby 1.9.3, I did a porting of a rails app from linux to windows, but in windows i'm having a lot of problems with mysql2 gem.
I installed mysql2 gem yesterday and than i tried to run rake db:migrate but i have this output:

> rake aborted!
>   Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (cannot load such file -- mysql2)
>   C:/Users/RoccaA/Desktop/project/config/environment.rb:5:in `'
>   Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Then this is my Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.9'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
#gem 'sqlite3'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
#  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
 # gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
gem 'jquery-rails'
# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'
# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'
# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'
# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
# this gems needs for auth
gem 'cancan'
gem 'devise'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby
gem 'populator'
gem 'faker'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'simple_xlsx_writer'
gem 'roo'
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.11'
gem 'simple_xlsx_writer'
gem 'rake', '~> 10.0.4'
gem 'icalendar'
```

And this is my database.yml

```
development:

  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: emc
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
testing:

  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: emc
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
production:

  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: emc
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I tried to solve this problem in a lots of ways, i read that i have to use mysql2 version < 0.3 but with this version I have this output

> WARNING: This version of mysql2 (0.2.18) isn't compatible with Rails 3.1 as the ActiveRecord adapter was pulled into Rails itself.
>   WARNING: Please use the 0.3.x (or greater) releases if you plan on using it in Rails >= 3.1.x
>   rake aborted!
>   undefined method `accept' for nil:NilClass
>   Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)**

Hope someone can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to you gemfile

instead of using:

```
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.11'
```

use this:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

This is working for me.

And by the way you have duplicate `gem`

```
gem 'simple_xlsx_writer'
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget about it.Insted of it use rails installer from http://www.railsinstaller.org/ it will automatically install mysql2 with ruby and rails with latest versions

Comment: I installed rails with rails installer, but I didn't see anything about mysql2, where can I find it?

Comment: This is the output when i try to install mysql2

**C:\Users\RoccaA\Desktop\project>gem install mysql2
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for main() in-llibmysql...no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.**

Answer (score 0):

Installing Rails and the mysql2 gem in windows is not as easy as on other os. But i found a good answer to your question:

[Unable to install MySQL2 gem on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367563/unable-to-install-mysql2-gem-on-windows-7)

The best thing to do is, to install rails on windows with the rubyinstaller.

Comment: I tried in this way too, but there is another error

**rake aborted!
Bad file descriptor
C:/Users/RoccaA/Desktop/project/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)**

Comment: What is in `/environment.rb:5`

Comment: This is envirorment.rb

1 # Load the rails application
2 require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
3 require 'coffee_script'
3 # Initialize the rails application
**5 ProgettoEmc2::Application.initialize!**

Answer (score 0):

```
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11"
```

and then `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

Good detailed steps here => http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/

Some key points are installing the right version of mysql, the dot net connector, and the gem.  Also be sure to place the libmysql file in the correct place.