# Error While Installing MYSQL Gems in Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I just need a big help while i was facing this for past 3 months.

I am using `windows 8` machine.

I was trying to install `ruby` in `rails`.Everything got success.

but while installing `mysql` gem i can face many errors which i have copied and pasted below

```
C:\Users\Mounarajan P A>gem install mysql
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -llibmysql... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

 Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
    --with-libmysqllib
    --without-libmysqllib


 Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql
-2.9.1 for inspection.
 Results logged to C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/mysql_
api/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually we should have the native development libraries when installing native extensions. For ubuntu it is libmysql2-dev, the same way find what is the dev lib for windows and install it. That could be solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to use the `mysql` gem?  I thought `mysql2` is now the standard/recommended gem to use with mysql databases.

Anyhow, this link might help you to get it installed:
[Unable to install mysql2 gem on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367563/unable-to-install-mysql2-gem-on-windows-7)

Comment: now -libmysql is installed but it again gives error as mysql.h is missing now what to do with this?

Comment: Do you actually have mysql installed?  That is required before you can install the gem.

Comment: Hi tried reinstalling mysql but when i install mysql it shows mysql cant install in port 3306 this is an installation error